# Programmably creating professional PDF documents for publishing

Tags: javascript, pdf, php

I would like to create a website to automatically generate high-end pdf documents based on a template I provide. The template would then be sent off to a publisher. The publisher is looking for the following features in the PDF document:

- Embedded ICC Color Profile
- Embedded fonts
- PDF/X-1a format
- Convert spot colors to process colors
- Use document bleeds
- CMYK colors

I am not too familiar with PDFs as related to professional printing, but I have been able to find those features in Desktop Publishing apps such as Scribus.

I am wondering if there is a web-related programming library that I can use to generate such PDFs.

I am most familiar with PHP and JavaScript so would prefer something in that realm, but would be open to alternatives if there are no adequate libraries for either.

The closest library I have found so far is TCPDF for PHP but it is lacking on some of those features (such as Embedded ICC Color profile) and/or the documentation is a bit lacking.

What libraries are available that would be able to accomplish this?